# Garantir que o teste unitário é valido em um IF. Unit Test

Tags: python, testes-de-unidade, tdd

Preciso criar um teste unitário que valide o seguinte código. Mas como posso garantir que o teste valide o conteúdo baixado e o obtido localmente?

```
if not (os.path.exists(filename)):
    melius.logger.debug('Obter codigo html on-line')
    codigo_html = melius.download(url)

    codigo_html = codigo_html.decode('utf-8')

else:
    melius.logger.debug('Obter codigo html off-line')

    with open(filename) as f:
        codigo_html = f.read()
        melius.logger.debug(f'carregado conteudo do arquivo local "{f.name}"')

melius.logger.debug(f'Download do atos de {ano} finalizado.')
```

Para facilitar digamos que o `codigo_html` é do tipo `str` e tenha o texto: `Janeiro` então basta um.

```
self.assertIn(codigo_html, 'Janeiro')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente testes automatizados (unitários/integração) vão até a "borda" do seu sistema, e no seu exemplo a "borda" do sistema é a requisição HTTP. Limitamos nossos testes à borda porque isso os torna mais determinísticos (não tem como garantir que o website que você está acessando durante os teste realmente retorna esse aquele conteúdo ou ainda que ele está no ar), e podemos rodá-lo mesmo onde não há conexão com a internet ou onde há conexão restrita.

Seu teste ficaria semelhante a esse:

```
@patch.object(melius, 'download', return_value='dummy content')
@patch.object(os.path, 'exists', return_value=True)
def test_my_function_returns_website_content(os_exists_patch, melius_download_patch):
    # Arrange
    filename = 'somefile.html'
    website_url = 'http://spam.egg'

    # Act
    response_text = my_function(filename, website_url)

    # Assert
    self.assertEqual('dummy_content', response_text)
    self.assertEqual(melius_download_patch.call_args_list, [mock.call(website_url)])
    self.assertEqual(os_exists_patch.call_args_list, [mock.call(filename)])
```

Em relação ao teste do `else` seria interessante mockar a função `open` também, e você pode fazer isso conforme descrito na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open).